# Regex out elements of server name in format of "ubuntu-prod-sfo1-01"

Tags: ruby, regex

Trying to extract out the individual elements of a server name in the format "ubuntu-prod-sfo1-01" which would give me the result of ["ubuntu","prod", "sfo1", "01"]. So everything between "-" AND the beginning element and ending element when end and start with "-", respectfully.

"ubuntu-prod-sfo1-01"  ==> ["ubuntu","prod", "sfo1", "01"]

My attempts at it have failed as the best solution I could find would give me the first "prod", but would fail to get each of the remaining elements. The problem seems to be the reusing of the '-' between the element.

Comment: which lang you're running? What's wrong with splitting on `-` ?

Comment: Doing this in Ruby. I can split, but I'd not get the first "ubuntu" and last "01".

Comment: Wouldn't be better to split the string on the `-`, like @AvinashRaj said, instead of using regex?

Comment: ok, split does work. Not sure how I missed that one.

Comment: Bonus,, `string.scan(/[^-]+/)`

Comment: Would you recommend that more than split? The result seems the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a string into substrings at a delimiter, in your case `-`.

```
string = "ubuntu-prod-sfo1-01"
string.split('-')
=> ["ubuntu", "prod", "sf01", "01"]
```

From the official documentation

> Divides str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these substrings.
>
> If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter when splitting str. If pattern is a single space, str is split on whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for that, you can just do...

```
"ubuntu-prod-sfo1-01".split('-')
=>  ["ubuntu","prod", "sfo1", "01"]
```